# Add a handwritten signature in IPAD

Tags: ipad, electronic-signature

In my application I need to get a handwritten signature saved as a jpg or such.

My problem is when I am using the IPAD and click on the link "Add file" the file explorer opens up to choose a file.

What I would like to happen is that when I click on the "Add link" a white space should opens up where I can write my signature with my finger.

Does anyone know if this would be possible and how I can do for making this?

Comment: in that case you have to implement something which can collect the signature, there are many nice examples abound the web which provides proper solution if you are not capable of implementing an own one. google is always your friend.

Answer (score 0):

I have Used handwritten Signature in my App , what I do is after capturing the Signature I convert it into an Image and then save that Image .. you can try doing the same

Comment: yes but it have to be really simple. What app do you use for capturing the Signature?

Comment: I used this Library which I found at https://github.com/IngmarStein/SignatureDemo, And then just converted that signature in an Image.